# Django Admin Column Sort Descending

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

When using Django admin with [grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) I would like that a click on a column header will sort the table by descending order.

(I don't want a default ordering to the columns by defining the ordering field in the Model Meta Class.)

The default behavior is Ascending.

The **first** click should order like this:

[image: required behavior]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the [`def result_headers(cl)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#LC88)

add these 2 lines:

```
    .....
    .....
    th_classes = ['sortable']
    order_type = ''

    #new lines

    default_order_type = getattr(attr, "admin_order_first_type", None)
    new_order_type = default_order_type if default_order_type else 'asc'

    #end of new lines

    sort_priority = 0
    sorted = False
    ...
    ...
```

now in the ModelAdmin you can:

```
list_display = ('number_of_players', ....)

def number_of_players(self, team):
        return intcomma(team.number_of_players)

number_of_players.short_description = '# num of players'
number_of_players.admin_order_field = 'number_of_players'
number_of_players.admin_order_first_type = 'desc' #will make the column to be ordered desc first
```

I tested it and it works