# Django admin default direction of sorting on first click

Tags: django, django-admin

When I *click* on table header in django admin it sorts data in ASC direction first. How can I change this default direction for some of columns?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910281/django-admin-column-sort-descending) to see if it helps.